# PHP file redirecting user when it is not supposed to

Tags: php

I'm making a login script for a Server CP although it doesn't seem to work as intended, I can login but if I go to the index page it doesn't redirect me to the admin page, code here:

All Code: http://pastebin.com/DC8fVtD5

Could anyone shed any light on this for me please? :) The problem is with the cookies or the sessions but I'm not sure how to fix it. The script needs to check user input against a mysql database and see if they have an account for the website and if so, log them in. It seems to be logging me in although admin.php seems to be redirecting me to index.php when $logged != 0. I haven't been able to find a fix for it and it is driving me nuts. D:

Comment: When you using `header()` to redirect you should also follow it up with `exit` or `die` to prevent anything else from being executed.  Have you checked to make sure that `$logged` is being set to the value you think it is?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget, that the variable

```
  $logged
```

if set in one script **isn't any longer set in the next script execution**: If you redirect using `header( 'Location: somewhere' );`, the current script terminates and **a new script gets started by a new HTTP-request** forces by the Location-header.

Please use [PHP's session-feature](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to **keep state through multiple requests/script-executions**.